# Check whether there is no match in any row in SQL

Tags: sql, join, orm, peewee

```
schedule = Session.select()
                  .join(Activity).join(Course)
                  .join(StuCouRel)
                  .join(Student)
                  .where(Student.id == current_user.id)
                  .join(StuActIgnore).where(Activity.id != StuActIgnore.activity)
```

Now, if StuActIgnore.activity has, say, three rows in this query, then it will have each session that 'gets through' output three times. It will compare each Session to *every* row in StuActIgnore.activity. I know what's going wrong; I just don't know how to fix it.

I want something like this:

```
schedule = Session.select()
                  .join(Activity).join(Course).join(StuCouRel).join(Student)
                  .where(Student.id == current_user.id)
                  .join(StuActIgnore)
                  .where(Activity.id not in StuActIgnore.activity)
```

that is; if Activity.id does not match for *any* StuActIgnore row, then the Session is added to the query. The code I wrote does not work because a ForeignKeyField is not iterable.

EDIT: I tried fixing it as follows:

```
schedule = Session.select()
                  .join(Activity)
                  .join(Course)
                  .join(StuCouRel)
                  .join(Student)
                  .where(Student.id == current_user.id)
                  .join(StuActIgnore)
                  .where(Activity not in current_user.ignoredactivities)
```

because this related_name ("ignoredactivities") is iterable, but this doesn't seem to work either.

EDIT2: I made it work by adding a separate for-loop. It works, but it's neither efficient nor elegant:

```
ignored = Activity.select().join(StuActIgnore).where(StuActIgnore.student == current_user.id)    
for element in schedule:
    if element.activity not in ignored:
        classes.append(element)
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing the same thing?